# TeamMod v1.1-alpha - Enables moderation features in Teams

Tags: app, script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, stack-overflow-for-teams

### I don't care, gimme the download link!

You can download the script from its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Anonymous941/TeamMod), or use the [direct download link](https://github.com/Anonymous941/TeamMod/raw/main/teammod.user.js).

### Credits

I've developed this by myself, but I'd like to thank [Tyberius from Matter Modeling Stack Exchange](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/7/tyberius) who [assisted development by sharing details about the moderator interface](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58144586#58144586). Version 0 uses [SO mod userscripts](https://github.com/BlackThunder01001/SO-mod-userscripts) as a template.

### To-do / known bugs

This is in alpha as I still have bugs to work out. Known bugs:

- When you edit or create a custom close reason, "an error occurred" pops up even though it still works
- Migration doesn't work
- "Admin settings" is highlighted even when you are in moderator tools
- After clicking "show all comments", the flag button disappears
- Certain actions cause the flag and mod buttons to disappear until you reload

### Screenshots

Some screenshots of the script in action:

[image: Moderator links]
[image: Flag review]
[image: Moderator post actions]
[image: User information]
[image: Moderator user actions]
[image: IP addresses]

### About

Have you ever wondered what it was like to be a moderator?  Or if you are a moderator, wish that you could perform some actions without repercussions (what *does* that delete user button do?  Too bad I haven't noticed a spammer yet...)?

Then this is for you! This script can be used to enable moderation actions on teams, including post actions, user actions, and site configuration. It can do the following:

#### Post actions

- Protect and unprotect questions
- Locks: historical lock, content dispute, comment lock, and wiki answer on both questions and answers
- All close reasons, not just the ones in teams
- Migration (coming soon)
- Purge comments
- Merge questions
- Post notices: needs citation, current event and needs detailed answers
- Convert answers to comments or edits
- Show deleted comments

#### User actions

- Annotate
- Clear sessions (logs them out on all Stack Exchange sites)
- Delete and destroy
- Send moderator private message and/or suspend
- Contact community team
- Show history, IP address, and various information about their team activity

#### Site actions

- A fully working flagging system!
- Creation of site-specific close reasons
- Site analysis
- Moderator tools

#### What happens if you try to destroy Community?

I'm sure you were wondering about this.

> User -1 cannot be destroyed because they are a moderator or an employee.
>
> Users who are moderators or employees can only be destroyed by a developer or community team member.
>
> The Stack Exchange community team has been notified.

Screenshot:

[image: "Moderator action failed" when trying to destroy community]

I don't know if it actually notifies the Stack Exchange community team though.

### License

This is released with the [GNU General Public License v3.0](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later).

### Platform

This app runs with the GreaseMonkey and TamperMonkey (as pointed out by [Oleg Valter](https://stackapps.com/users/78873/oleg-valter) in [the comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/8949/teammod-v1-0-alpha-enables-moderation-features-in-teams#comment18253_8949) extensions and is supported on all browsers that can install it.

### Contact

If you have any comments, questions, or ideas to add to the list of moderator actions, post them as an answer and I'll respond shortly.

### How can I help?

If you want to do something to assist, let me know as an answer if I missed any moderator features you would like to see or any other suggestions.

Comment: Feature request: https://stackoverflow.com/c/<teamname>/admin/links links should be edited to redirect to /c/teamname/admin/<path> instead of /admin/<path>

Comment: @smileycreations15 Implemented!  Update to version 0.0.3 to see the change.

Comment: Thanks, there are a lot of links lying around that have this issue so there might need to be more link editing via JS. Or is your patch /admin/links specific?

Comment: @smileycreations15 My patch applies for all links that start with `/admin` plus `/annotated-posts` (specifically that URL, but not sub-URLs) on all team pages (so not just `/admin/links`).  There may be others, and unfortunately I can't patch every URL or else it would be impossible to open the Stack Overflow home page within teams (for instance).  Let me know if you notice any others and I'll patch them.

Comment: I think you should remove the "**What happens if you try to destroy Community**" section and add it as an answer.

Comment: @Tec Why?  It doesn't seem like it should be its own answer...

Comment: On the note of Greasemonkey - why not add support for Tampermonkey as well? You don't seem to use `GM.*` functions, and apart from `@grant` headers and differences in APIs, they are pretty much the same thing, but TM (and Violentmonkey as the OS alternative) seem to be much more popular these days

Comment: @OlegValter That's a good point, I'll look into adding TM support for the next version.

Comment: @Anonymous no rush - I think you can simple check if it works if loaded via it - a quick glance at the source showed that you only need `unsafeWindow` to be present, but it is in both extensions, so should work just fine

Comment: @OlegValter As far as I can tell, the script runs exactly the same way if I simply run it on TamperMonkey instead of GreaseMonkey.

Comment: @Anonymous as expected :) You can safely claim support for both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One caveat is that some moderator actions are directly linked to SO instead of the team, and then an admin will have to manually copypaste the `/c/<teamname>` part to perform that action. For example, the [link in the screenshot below](https://stackoverflow.com/admin/show-user-votes/20) doesn't work. Note that 20 is the user ID of the user in question.[image: Screenshot of a link that doesn't work1]

Comment: Yeah, it's an issue that some Stack Exchange URLs are broken like this.  I'm trying to patch any URLs I can find so that the script adds `/c/<teamname>/` to the URL but I have to patch each one manually so I missed a few.  Thanks for bringing this to my attention, I'll fix it in the next update.